# How to create a Dash Callback without an output?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

It is required for an output to have a callback in Dash, but what if you want to trigger events in the backend without having anything output on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Output` with a `component_id` that doesn't exist in the layout and set the `component_property='children'`

```
@callback(
    Output('none', 'children'),
    ...
)...
```